# A Suggestion for an scroll anchor for "ng-repeated" images in portfolio page?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, anchor

I have a page in my portfolio site (which is built with AngularJS) where from a local json, a series of 4 images are displayed via an ng-repeat.

```
 "images": ["../assets/img/details/2/1.jpg",
            "../assets/img/details/2/2.jpg",
            "../assets/img/details/2/3.jpg",
            "../assets/img/details/2/4.jpg"],
```

I have looked into creating a vertically aligned "dot navigation" that will float to the right of the page so users don't have to scroll loads; as the pages once the work is on view, is quite long.  I have seen a few examples of using angularjs' "scrollto", but this requires static html divs with several different ids to anchor to.

Could anyone suggest a way by which I could anchor to the repeated images that are coming from the array object in my json file? I am a little stuck as to how I might do this?

Thanks for the suggestions in advance.

Comment: How about `imgElement.scrollIntoView()` ?

Comment: Hi Mohamed, thanks for this, as a function this makes sense, my only question would be will these 4 images be distinguished once in view?